# General form of elements in $ \mathbb{Z} [\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} ] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the general form of elements in $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} \right] $?

I'm getting muddled.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the definition of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is (for, say, $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: I do. It's the ring of (finite) sums of powers of $ \alpha $, with integer coefficients.

Comment: If $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, can you express the square of $\alpha$ as sum of $1$ and $\alpha$ with integer coefficients ?

Comment: since $\alpha^2-\alpha+1=0$ you can write all elements as $a+b\alpha, a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: So combine that with the fact that $\rm\ \alpha^2 \in \alpha\ \mathbb Z + \mathbb Z\ $ to conclude that $\ \mathbb Z[\alpha] \cong \ldots$

Answer (score 4):

In general, if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer (satisfies a monic polynomial with integer coefficients), and its monic irreducible is of degree $n$, then the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ can be written uniquely as
$$a_0 + a_1\alpha + \cdots + a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1},\qquad a_i\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
(A simple application of the remainder theorem for polynomials, and the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] = {p(\alpha)\mid p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]}$).

So here, the simplest is to note that $\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ satisfies a monic polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

In this particular case, there is an alternative possible description: every element of $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$ can be written uniquely as
$$\frac{a + b\sqrt{-3}}{2},\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad a\equiv b\pmod{2}.$$